# Is there a database that has information on the typological variation of honorific systems?

Tags: linguistic-typology

For a class project, I need a typology of the grammatical honorific systems of the world's languages. Specifically, I need to categorize languages into whether they have honorifics for second or third person or both. Also, I need to know how many levels of honorifics are present within each person.

Is anyone aware of a database or other resource that has information about languages and their honorific systems?

Many thanks!

Comment: One place to start would be WALS's chapter on [Politeness Distinctions in Pronouns](http://wals.info/chapter/45). There are a number of different kinds of politeness systems.